# QGIS Plugin for PostGIS versioning

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins, versioning

Does anyone of you know a QGIS-Plugin for Versioning PostGIS-Data?
I know there was pgVersion of Horst Düster but as far as I know this was not updated for QGIS 2.x (at least not for the "normal" QGIS aside from QGIS Enterprise.
The searched functionality is:
Setting up versioning for a Layer
Managing conflicts that were detected (resulting from concurrent editing)

old Plugin pgVersion: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pgversion/

Answer (score 3):

What about the Oslandia Versioning Plugin for QGIS?

http://www.oslandia.com/qgis-versioning-plugin-en.html

Contrary to the promises on the website, I can't find it in the QGIS Plugin Repository.

Comment: In QGIS 2.8.7 I just found this plugin called 'versioning'.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no PostGIS-Versioning plugin available at the moment. Perhaps you could have a look at the old Version in the still existing SVN to get an Idea of how to implement one of your own?
https://www.kappasys.ch/svn/pgversion/branches/pgversion_branch/

If you use the plugin builder you can get an up to date "skeleton" for a new Plugin:
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/

Another alternative to the "normal" versioning would be geogig (http://geogig.org/docs/index.html) or the hosted version versio.io (at the moment as private beta):
http://versio.io/docs/qgis-intro
I think this looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FastVersion/

Is a Qgis plugin that integrates with Postgres-Postgis database and allows versioning, user security administration and project management.