# Spatial Data Version Control or Versioning Software

Tags: postgis, versioning

I have a lot of shapefile or fgdb feature classes that I am working with now and it gets updated almost every month.

As of right now, I am just making the file name with extra name after '-'
(i.e., road_network_Jan2018_v1, road_network_Jan2018_v2, ... road_network_Feb2018_v1, and so forth)

I was wondering will there be an awesome spatial data versioning software that can improve efficiency of my works.

I am usually edit stuff uing ArcMap and QGIS and import them to PostGIS

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the GIS software you are using.

Comment: Are you licensed for, and have you looked at [geodatabase versioning](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/what-is-a-version.htm)?

Comment: Some options were discussed (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132419/qgis-plugin-for-postgis-versioning)[here] ages ago

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `geogig`:

http://geogig.org/

This is like "git for spatial data". There's a learning curve (as with all new software).

Answer (score -2):

Irrespective of data/file format, using version controlling software for versioning the files will be a good solution. U may use desktop based or server based SVN tools.

Comment: Why is it a good solution?

Comment: Most conventional version control software works terribly on binary files, which shapefiles and fgdbs are.

Comment: Source control tools are not a best fit for binary file management. Have you actually tried this before recommending it?